# AngularFire2 - Subscription Query

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am subscribing to a list in my firebase database.
I was wondering how to filter/query using one of each items property?

This is what I am currently using to get back the entire list:

```
 return this.af.database.list('items');
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md#creating-a-query-with-observable-values

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to filter your search results

```
let searchTerm = 'somevalue';

return this.af.database.list('items', {
  query: {
     orderByChild: 'property',
     equalTo: searchTerm
  }
});
```

More information on querying lists [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md#creating-a-query-with-observable-values)